# Downloading a file using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am writing a web scraping script in python and I have to download a file. On the website , there is an image `<a href="javascript:DownloadMyFile();">`. When I click it, it calls a function which brings the dialog to save or open the file. How do I download the file using python directly using beautiful soup?

Comment: Can you give a web page from which you are trying to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup does not render JavaScript, so you have two options:

1. Figure out what the JavaScript is doing to generate the url that is handed to your browser when you click that anchor.
2. Write your scraper using something modern like CasperJS -- it can handle JavaScript.